# Migrated RHEL 7.9 VM from vSphere to VMware Workstation and networking is now broken

Tags: networking, vmware-workstation, vsphere

I have other VMs running in VMware Workstation that run perfectly fine, so it must be something with this Red Hat VM...? However, I migrated a Windows VM from vSphere as a test and it also has the same issue - IP settings were retained but I **cannot ping the gateway at all.**

To migrate the VMs I shut them down gracefully, then copied the entire VM folder over from vSphere to Workstation. The VM starts up and looks normal, VM-Tools is running.

Comment: The networking likely changed from Bridged (Vshpere) to NAT (Workstation).  Can you change the networking to Bridged to check this?

Comment: Thanks, John. Negative, the networking is still set to Bridged. I added a new NIC (also Bridged), but the issue persists.

Comment: In my Ubuntu guest (Workstation Host) I can go to network settings and delete the connection profile. I would then restart and make a new network. Is that something you can try?

Comment: Thanks, @John. The RHEL has no GUI but I'm sure I can try that via the CLI, yes. Let me see...